.Net - How to check if process is app or background in system space?
The question is in addition to below question.
.NET How to check if a Windows process is running as an "App" or as a "Background application"
I have a requirement to list down all processes and whether it is running as background or an app.
I am using Process.MainWindowTitle or Process.MainWindowHandle to identify if it is background/app.
 Process[] arrProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
 File.AppendAllText("C:\\processesList.txt", $"-----------------------------------------------------------. {Environment.NewLine}");
 foreach (Process process in arrProcess)
 {
     string processType = "Background";
     if (process.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
     {
         processType = "App";
     }

     File.AppendAllText("C:\\processesList.txt", $"Name = {process.ProcessName}. Id = {process.Id}. MainWindowTitle = {process.MainWindowTitle}. ProcessType = {processType}. {Environment.NewLine}");
 }

The code is correctly able to identify if it is background/app when run in user mode but in system mode it gives empty MainWindowTitle and MainWindowHandle.
I need to get the same results in system mode. Is there some setting/alternative to get the same results in system mode. I am open to any suggestions in C#/C++

It uses EnumWindows under the hood https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/42f2b33e9f2028b50ddb2046439e7a8d8630836c/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/ProcessManager.Win32.cs#L38 and you are not allowed to enumerate anyone else's windows.
